# Listening to and calling wxPython event from another process

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, ipc

I'm currently trying to develop a proof of concept for a possible idea but am unsure if this is even possible.

We have application A, written in wxPython, which will **not** receive any code updates. It's too late in its life and will impact too many people. In a specific case which we wish to automatic - a GUI window pops up asking user to select an option from the list.

We want to develop script or "application B" which listens for this GUI to pop up and automatically makes the choice. It can be a script that runs in the background at all times.

Now.. from my understanding I don't think it's possible without some interprocess communication going on. Since we cannot change anything in application A the problem seems unsolvable. Any ideas? Am I missing something about how I could use wxPython?

Comment: You don't mention your OS but under Linux you could possibly do something with `xdotool` `xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible  --name "your window title"` will wait untl it sees a given window. You can then focus it and send mouse or key instructions.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Oh this is a good resource thank you. Do you know if it's possible to "read" the contents of the window with this tool? There's a list of items and I need to choose one and press OK. Screen sizes could vary by server and the options can vary. So X Y coords won't cut it.

Comment: Doubt it. I assumed you'd always perform the same action. Sounds like you need an app with an Imp sat inside, pushing buttons. :D